# Selecting from 10 listboxes . Runtime Error "390"

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Below the code using for 10 listbox control 10 items. Users choose listboxes' items and stores to activesheet related row and column, run perfectly. Also in the userform there are Spindown_up and _down button.

When the user down or up to the spindown buttons code get the related values from the given row and columns. Fort the first or second usage up or down to spindown without any problems. But after 2 or more usage spindown button errors occurs :

> Runtime Error "390". Could not set the selected property. Invalid
> property value. UserForm Listbox Selected property problem.

```
Sub get_decad(rnum As Integer)

Dim first_row, last_row As Integer
first_row = 57
last_row = 65

If rnum >=first_line  And rnum <= last_row Then
UserForm1.TextBox1 = ActiveSheet.Range("ca" & rnum)
UserForm1.TextBox2 = ActiveSheet.Range("cc" & rnum)
UserForm1.TextBox3 = ActiveSheet.Range("ce" & rnum)
UserForm1.TextBox4 = ActiveSheet.Range("cg" & rnum)
UserForm1.TextBox5 = ActiveSheet.Range("ci" & rnum)
UserForm1.TextBox6 = ActiveSheet.Range("ck" & rnum)
UserForm1.TextBox7 = ActiveSheet.Range("cm" & rnum)
UserForm1.TextBox8 = ActiveSheet.Range("co" & rnum)
UserForm1.TextBox9 = ActiveSheet.Range("cq" & rnum)
UserForm1.TextBox10 = ActiveSheet.Range("cs" & rnum)

   For iCount = 1 To 10
       
        Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCount) = False
        Me.ListBox2.Selected(iCount) = False
        Me.ListBox3.Selected(iCount) = False
        Me.ListBox4.Selected(iCount) = False
        Me.ListBox5.Selected(iCount) = False
        Me.ListBox6.Selected(iCount) = False
        Me.ListBox7.Selected(iCount) = False
        Me.ListBox8.Selected(iCount) = False
        Me.ListBox9.Selected(iCount) = False
        Me.ListBox10.Selected(iCount) = False
    Next iCount

UserForm1.ListBox10.Selected(ActiveSheet.Range("cs" & rnum)) = True
UserForm1.ListBox9.Selected(ActiveSheet.Range("cq" & rnum)) = True
UserForm1.ListBox8.Selected(ActiveSheet.Range("co" & rnum)) = True
UserForm1.ListBox7.Selected(ActiveSheet.Range("cm" & rnum)) = True
UserForm1.ListBox6.Selected(ActiveSheet.Range("ck" & rnum)) = True
UserForm1.ListBox5.Selected(ActiveSheet.Range("ci" & rnum)) = True
UserForm1.ListBox4.Selected(ActiveSheet.Range("cg" & rnum)) = True
UserForm1.ListBox3.Selected(ActiveSheet.Range("ce" & rnum)) = True
UserForm1.ListBox2.Selected(ActiveSheet.Range("cc" & rnum)) = True
UserForm1.ListBox1.Selected(ActiveSheet.Range("ca" & rnum)) = True

Else
' do nothing
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the point.

My mistake was trying to .selected("the value"). It should be .selected("Item Index Number").